# PHP framework suggestions

Tags: php, payment-gateway, django

I'm going to be creating a site for a business with the following:

- Single Item purchases with Paypal, Google Checkout and Amazon Checkout
- Digital Downloads for members from a CDN
- Forum
- Voting on different items

While that seems rather simple having to deal with the three different payment gateways is a big pain in the ass. Django has a great payment library which works for all three but I'm not able to find one for any of the PHP frameworks.

Anyone have any suggestions?

I'm posting here as suggested by someone at Stackoverflow.

Comment: This must be a duplicate question but I can't find it.

Comment: It seems like a too localized version of a _Which framework to choose?_ question, which itself is either not constructive or should be community wikied.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with Symfony (1.4 or 2.0). A lot of plugins (called bundles on Symfony 2) has been created.

- Symfony 2.0: [symfony.com](http://www.symfony.com) ([bundles](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=payment))
- Symfony 1.4: [symfony-project.org](http://www.symfony-project.org/) ([plugins](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/category/Payments))

No experience with symfony payment bundles, sorry, but good for work.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework has a lot of built in functions and probably the most popular

Answer (score 0):

My Framework of choice at the moment is [Silverstripe](http://silverstripe.org), It's relatively new compared to some of the bigger frameworks out there, but the code is easy to use and follow, the documentation (particularly the tutorials) are up-to-date and awesome, and plugin development etc. is very easy.

I am currently looking to make an eCommerce website, and went to look at what eCommerce modules there were, and apparently theres 2 good ones, 2 bad ones, and this new one, [swipestripe](http://swipestripe.com/) which the developer is releasing later this week. I'm hanging out to try that.